# How should I reference a session from a Django model?

Tags: python, django, session, foreign-keys

I get an error on attempting a syncdb when I try to add a ForeignKey to a session:

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1156, in __init__
    assert isinstance(to, six.string_types), "%s(%r) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string %r" % (self.__class__.__name__, to, RECURSIVE_RELATIONSHIP_CONSTANT)
AssertionError: ForeignKey(<class 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.base.SessionBase'>) is invalid. First parameter to ForeignKey must be either a model, a model name, or the string 'self'
```

What is the best way to reference a session like a Django model? I think I could add an identifier by assigning a value to a session as a hash, and then offloading the work elsewhere. It would also work if I could refer to User objects in a way that would work with anonymous users, if it would treat different users differently.

More basically, I am trying to reference one user at one computer without making users create authenticated login information to use the webapp.

Comment: can you how us some piece of code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: are you basically trying to store data in the session object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django. How to get session and save it as a Foreign Key.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35468307/django-how-to-get-session-and-save-it-as-a-foreign-key)

Answer (score 3):

Make a `Foreign Key` to `django.contrib.sessions.models.Session.`