# Django. How to get session and save it as a Foreign Key.

Tags: django

This is a simple question. I have a model with a FK to session:

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey('sessions.Session', blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

When I save the model I need to do something like this:

```
if form.is_valid():
    booking = form.save(commit=False)
    booking.session = HOW CAN I GET THE SESSION?
    booking.save()
```

Comment: Can I ask why you need to save the session? What are you trying to use it for?

Comment: @Sayse Cause in the site you don't need to login to create a booking. I want to keep track of the sessions that created bookings. And be able to get all the bookings created by one session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
request.session
```

This will return a SessionStore Object

However depending on what you are trying to do with the session, this answer can very quickly become irrelevant.

This section has very helpful information on using sessions in views: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views

Comment: Can't save a SessionStore Object as the FK. `"Booking.session" must be a "Session" instance.` How do I get the Session instance?

Comment: Have you tried using `request.session.session_key`?

Comment: Yep. Similar error. Cant save a string in FK field.

Comment: The session table is an implementation detail of the DB-backed session store (i.e. best to consider private in case you ever want to switch session backends). It would be best not to store a FK to it, but rather store the session key and then use the public session API to retrieve it when needed.

Comment: That being said, getting a instance should be accomplished with `Session.objects.get(session_key=request.session.session_key)`

Comment: Ok thanks for your comments. I'll store the session key.

Comment: @JoeHolloway Wouldn't the session key format (`CharField` with `max_length=40`) also be considered an implementation detail?

Comment: @Felipe I guess it depends on what level of abstraction you're working with, but it's not a detail that's coupled to a single session store backend as would be FK(session_id). All session store implementations must speak the same concept of session key as defined by the API. The fact that having one longer than 40 characters would break the DB backend is a bit of an abstraction leak, perhaps? I don't think that changes anything here, though.  If you want your model to be agnostic to what backend you're using you should store the key, not the DB ID.